# clase y main con metodos

Tags: java, poo

este es mi metodo recargar una cuenta de tipo double.
llevar la clase recargar a main y me sume el saldo ingresado por teclado.
y que me muestre el saldo. no me entrega en resultado no se porque? agradezco su ayuda

clase encargado.
con su metodo

```
public double recargar(double monto,double saldo){
        saldo = monto + saldo;
        return saldo;
    }
```

y mi main principal.

```
System.out.println("Ingrese Saldo a recargar Para el Jugador");
                        recargar = leer.nextDouble();
                        encargado.recargar(recargar, recargar);
```

Answer (score 0):

A ver , si no te presenta errores , el valor que quieres mostrar deberia estar en:

```
encargado.recargar()
```

Podrias cargarlo en un

```
system.out.println(encargado.recargar(x,x));
```

y se terminaría mostrando .

Ahora noto que a **`encargado.recargar(recargar,recargar)`** le cargas el mismo parámetro tanto para el saldo( que yo creo que seria el saldo actual ?) como para el monto próximo a recargar, yo creo que bastaria con recibir solo una vez la recarga en el método **`encargado.recargar(recargar)`** e igual podrías tener acceso a los montos actuales de cada usuario . y aqui puedo comentar otra cosa .

Dentro de este método está pasando lo siguiente , el saldo que recibe en su segundo parametro la función, creo que si cambias el nombre de la variable local "saldo"(no la que se recibe el parametro) a digamos **`saldo1 = monto + saldo`**, habiendo declarado antes **`saldo1 = new double();`** , podría ser que funcione, (creo que se cruzan las variables , ya que en cada función o procedimiento se crean variables locales , entonces si la variable local tiene el mismo nombre que un parámetro , se podría rayar , corríjanme si estoy mal porfavor).

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 0):

El motivo es porque estas llamando a la funcion que devuelve el resultado pero no lo estas imprimiendo.Para imprimirlo tendrias hacer lo siguiente:

```
System.out.println(encargado.recargar(x,y));
```

Donde esta x e y irian los valores.Lo que hace esto es mostrarte en consola el resultado.

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda voy a ver